# GoJS: How to add background image to diagram

Tags: gojs

How can I add a background image to a GoJS diagram?
When I drag or zoom the diagram the background image should move and zoom accordingly.

The background image should als be visible in an associated [Overview diagram](https://gojs.net/latest/intro/overview.html).

Is there a simple (or not so simple) way to archieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to move and zoom, etc, then just add it as a separate Part, like they do in Floor Monitor:

```
  // the background image, a floor plan
  myDiagram.add(
    $(go.Part,  // this Part is not bound to any model data
      { layerName: "Background", position: new go.Point(0, 0),
        selectable: false, pickable: false },
      $(go.Picture, "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Sample_Floorplan.jpg")
    ));
```

https://gojs.net/latest/samples/kittenMonitor.html